# Isset and actual value contradiction in my case

Tags: php

```
  $fb_userIdCookie = get_cookie('fb_userId'); 

 var_dump($fb_userIdCookie); false
  var_dump(($fb_userIdCookie != '')); false
```

this mean contradiction isn't it? I tried isset($fb_userIdCookie) it return true. Omg I check in the resources tab, it has no fb_userId there..

Comment: `isset()` is true even if the string is empty or NULL

Comment: That is not true. Check my answer, or the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset()` check check if a variable exist or not.

You're `get_cookie('fb_userId');` probably return false. Wich does that `$fb_userIdCookie` is a boolean type variable with the value `false`

Answer (score 0):

As per `isset` documentation:

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php